# addClass to closest span with class

Tags: jquery, find

I'm trying to add a Class on mouseover on the element "goto" and give class "active" to the arrow with class "arrow", how is this done?

```
  $('.goto').on('mouseover',function() {
 $('.goto').find('.arrow').addClass('active')  
 })

<span class="goto">Hover here<span class="arrow"><img src="assets/img/arrow.png">    </span></span>
<span class="goto">Hover here<span class="arrow"><img src="assets/img/arrow.png"></span></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbFb9/)**

Use this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.goto').on('mouseover',function() {
        $(this).find('.arrow').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Also you can attach `mouseout` to put it back:

```
$(function () {
    $('.goto')
        .on('mouseover',function() {
            $(this).find('.arrow').addClass('active');
        })
        .on('mouseout',function() {
            $(this).find('.arrow').removeClass('active');
        });
});
```

---

### TIP

You can do this with CSS only, in this situation, there is no need to use jQuery:

```
.goto:hover .arrow {
    /* rules for make it active */
}
```

- You can check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbFb9/1/) for CSS only.

Comment: Thank you for a great explaination!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually searching for every `.goto` when you hover one. Use this :

```
$(this).find('.arrow').addClass('active')
```

`this` is the reference of the hovered `.goto`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.goto .arrow').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```